# How to select and replace last occurrence of column value in postgres query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Database structure is as follow -

Table : account_name

```
id | string_name
1  | "110\u001F121\u001FHELLO"
2  | "110\u001F121\u001FBYE"
3  | "110\u001F122\u001FTAP"
```

I want to select uniq string_name from table account_name as follow
expected output -

```
string_name
"110\u001F121\u001FNOTHING"
"110\u001F122\u001FNOTHING"
```

here record with id=2 cannot be selected as after adding NOTHING it will be the same as record with id=1. Also, `\u001F` this is a special character, it prints this character on rails console but shows blank space in pgadmin output and the format of string_name is not fixed as there may be any number of chunks connected by `\u001F`. We only want to replace text after last occurrence of `\u001F`.

Comment: @Akina This is not what am I trying to fetch.

Comment: ```SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(string_name, 17) || 'NOTHING' string_name
FROM account_name;``` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=088c9767bd4a34a19b2966def58be741

Comment: This is good but the thing is the format is not fix, cannot hardcode 17. 'NOTHING' should be added after the last occurrence of '\u001F' that is character separator.

Comment: I have tried something like this but it looks complicated
`REGEXP_REPLACE(string_name, substring(string_name from '%\u001F#"%#"%' for '#'), 'NOTHING')`

Comment: your solution looks simpler if we can avoid hardcoded 17 finding last occurrence of `\u001F`, want to replace all the text after `\u001F` with NOTHING keeping `\u001F`

Comment: *the format is not fix, cannot hardcode 17* You have not provided this critical information. In this case the solution with REGEXP_REPLACE seems to be optimal.

Comment: Thank you @Akina. Can this be optimised any further ?

Comment: Think about normalization and storing the string divided by its logically solid parts.

Comment: Hey @Akina Could you help me understand how does `\1` works in this regex
`DISTINCT REGEXP_REPLACE(account_string, \'(.*\\u001F).*$\', '\1NOTHING')` ?

Comment: If the pattern is found then each pattern part enclosed with the parenthesis is saved, and all of them are enumerated. In your pattern `'(.*\\u001F).*$'` there is only one such part, and it have number 1. When the replacement pattern comtains `\N` placeholder then it is replaced with the value of according saved substring number N. See https://regex101.com/r/G3q5Ud/1 and study EXPLANATION window.